# Creating a treeview in the android with the rendering tree in a line

Tags: java, android

tell me how to create a treeview in the android with the rendering tree in by a line?
I have a database of the database, I get the parent and his children, and then the data I need to to withdraw in a fragment.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is offtopic or not, but this library may help you solve your issue: https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ . You will need to create adapters as well, the tutorial should help some. The lib Shark gave should work perfectly though

Comment: @Lunchbox was thinking about ExpandableListView but the description scarcity made me wonder between Vote to close > Off-topic > Recommendation for a library, ExpandableListView or the TreeView i found... it was in the first five google results when searching "treeview". So i'm not getting the point of the question, and we can't just post `What have you tried?` anymore...

Comment: @Shark True story bro. Owel, between the two I guess he should find his answer. Lack of effort I reckon - reason, should be fairly obvious.

Comment: you have any idea?